# defining the UDP socket for the nodes located in different networks

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, udp

Let's assume there are two linux machines that are located in two different networks have the following configurations

```
                              Node1           Node2
IPaddr(private)          192.168.0.14     10.25.3.75
Router modem's IP(real)   1.2.3.4          5.6.7.8
Netmask (real)           255.255.0.0      255.255.192.0
Router modem's IP(priv)  192.168.0.1      10.0.20.1
Netmask (priv)           255.255.255.0    255.0.0.0
```

Here below is a generic UDP (client) socket code in `C` (error check is not included to save space on the question). Assume that the below could would be run on the `node1`. My question is that **how** do I need to define the `node2` on the below code and **what else** do I need to edit so that UDP packet from `node1 to node2` would be delivered without any problem?

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define SRV_IP "5.6.7.8"

int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sockfd, i, slen=sizeof(serv_addr);
    char buf[512] = "hello";
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    inet_aton(SRV_IP, &serv_addr.sin_addr);
    sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, slen);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

I assume the UDP server part (on `node2`) is a generic code and does not need any specific modification to receive the packet from the `node1`, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routing UDP packets (as well as TCP) is not the task you should solve in your code, it is performed by routers.  You should write your code as if both client and server are on the same network (your current code looks ok), BUT you should also set up your routers so that they: 1) allow routing UDP through NAT, and 2) the router for the Node2 (5.6.7.8) must forward its UDP traffic for port 1234 to the Node2's private address.

Comment: I am curios about one more question. I have not paid attention that UDP 1234 is an already defined port. Do you know if there is any multi-purpose UDP port number that I can use on the socket, so that I would not need to deal with port forwarding on the router (as I might not have access to the router to configure)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware about a commonly used UDP port that is open on all routers, and I am afraid such ports wouldn't be multi-purpose. But anyway, you cannot have a server behind a NAT (i.e. a server without 'real' IP-address) without setting up port forwarding at the router serving the NAT.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code from my college days, hope this will help

```
/* Sample UDP server */

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   socklen_t len;
   char mesg[1000];

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);
   bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

   for (;;)
   {
      len = sizeof(cliaddr);
      n = recvfrom(sockfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);
      sendto(sockfd,mesg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
      printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
      mesg[n] = 0;
      printf("Received the following:\n");
      printf("%s",mesg);
      printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
   }
}
```

and a client

```
/* Sample UDP client */

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   char sendline[1000];
   char recvline[1000];

   if (argc != 2)
   {
      printf("usage:  udpcli <IP address>\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);

   while (fgets(sendline, 10000,stdin) != NULL)
   {
      sendto(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline),0,
             (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
      n=recvfrom(sockfd,recvline,10000,0,NULL,NULL);
      recvline[n]=0;
      fputs(recvline,stdout);
   }
}
```